# What is the name of the condition when I temporarily cannot speak because of shouting too much?

Tags: vocabulary, medical

What is that condition called in English when I can't say anything, "lose my voice", due to shouting a lot?

I think it is related to my vocal chords. The usual treatment prescribed is just to stay silent for a period of one or two weeks.

Comment: Is there some other language in which this exact phenomenon has a name?

Comment: I'd just say "I've gone hoarse."

Comment: "I've lost my voice" is also a common way to describe the condition in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A technical term could be **[Dysphonia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoarse)**

> Dysphonia is the medical term for disorders of the voice: an impairment in the ability to produce voice sounds using the [vocal organs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_apparatus) (it is distinct from [dysarthria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysarthria) which means disorders of speech, that is, an impairment in the ability to produce spoken words). Thus, dysphonia is a [phonation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonation) disorder. The dysphonic voice can be hoarse or weak, or excessively breathy, harsh, or rough, but some kind of phonation is still possible (contrasted with the more severe aphonia where phonation is impossible).

The other term (if you *completely* lose your voice) would be **[Aphonia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphonia)**: the inability to speak.
[aphonia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aphonia): loss of voice and of all but whispered speech.

Answer (score 14):

A rough or harsh voice, typically the result of a sore throat or shouting, is called *hoarse*, the state or quality of a *hoarse* voice being *hoarseness*.

If you shout for too long, your larynx will become inflamed. This condition is called *[laryngitis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laryngitis)*, although laryngitis can be caused by other things, such as a viral or bacterial infection. Often people with an inflamed larynx will have trouble speaking. The generic term for disorders of the voice is *[dysphonia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphonia)*.

So if you can't talk because you were shouting too much, you could say your voice is hoarse from shouting, or that you have dysphonia caused by laryngitis.

Answer (score 7):

It's called laryngitis.

http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0458130#m_en_gb0458130

Comment: But is laryngitis not due to catching a cold and the following process of inflammation rather then because of shouting for too long?

Comment: "Using your voice excessively" may also be a cause. Here's a link to Merck's Manual: http://www.merckmanuals.com/home/sec19/ch222/ch222d.html

Answer (score 2):

There is an idiom for that:

**To have a frog in one's throat**
*(verb) to lose your voice and be unable to speak*

Examples:

> After her 21st birthday, Rachel had a
>   frog in her throat because she stayed
>   out all night singing Karaoke.
>
> We will have to cancel the concert
>   tonight if you have a frog in your
>   throat.
>
> David cannot come in to work today
>   because he has a frog in his throat.

Comment: "frog in one's throat" just means hoarseness or a lump in one's throat; it's not necessarily because of shouting too much. (It's even ["often regarded as a sign of fear"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throat).) AFAIK it doesn't even necessarily mean you're unable to speak, only that you're speaking very hoarsely and with difficulty.

Comment: It has multiple meanings as you said, but I heard it's used in cases when you lose your voice because of shouting, etc. One of its meanings is *any temporary physical difficulty in speaking*. I won't delete my answer as it's an alternative answer to the question. Anyway, thanks for your supplement.